# Можно ли как-нибудь в класс передать параметр?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Есть такой класс:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Form >
            <Input placeholder='Search' />
            <Button type='button' onClick={onFetch}>GO</Button>
        </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

можно ли добавить параметр, как здесь:

```
const SearchBar = ({onFetch}) => {
return (
    <Form >
        <Input placeholder='Search' />
        <Button type='button' onClick={onFetch}>GO</Button>
    </Form>
  )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
    onFetch: () =>
        dispatch({
            type: 'IMAGE_FETCH_REQUESTED'
         })
    }
}

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchBar);
```

Или нужно будет обернуть render?

Comment: что такое onFetch и как он передается в SearchBar?

Comment: @Grundy функция, через connect из redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функциональные компоненты в качестве параметра передается `props`.

Поэтому первый пример можно переписать как:

```
const SearchBar = (props) => {
  return (
    <Form >
        <Input placeholder='Search' />
        <Button type='button' onClick={props.onFetch}>GO</Button>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Далее можно воспользоваться советом из документации: [конвертация функции в класс](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class)

Важен четвертый шаг: заменить `props` на `this.props`

В итоге получится:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Form >
            <Input placeholder='Search' />
            <Button type='button' onClick={this.props.onFetch}>GO</Button>
        </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,то что нужно)